# X has finitely many connected components, can we get X locally connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, locally-connected

say X has finitely many connected components, can we get X locally connected?

I'm thinking to prove this and then I can have every component is open.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: for instance, the space $X=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,:\, x=0\lor y=\sin\frac1x\right\}$ with the topology inherited from $\Bbb R^2$ is connected, but not locally connected (all sufficiently small balls around $(0,t)$ for $t\in[0,1]$ contain infinitely many cuts of the topologist's sine curve but not a whole arc connecting them).

However, it is true that a topological space with finitely many connected components has all connected components open. This is because the connected components of a topological space are always *closed*, and therefore each connected component is $C_i=X\setminus\bigcup_{1\le j\le m\\ j\ne i} C_j$, which is in fact the complement of a closed set.

Comment: Thank you! This makes much sense!